# Fastest way to identify differences between two tables?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, plsql

I have a need to check a live table against a transactional archive table and I'm unsure of the fastest way to do this...

For instance, let's say my live table is made up of these columns:

- Term
- CRN
- Fee
- Level Code

My archive table would have the same columns, but also have an archive date so I can see what values the live table had at a given date.

Now... How would I write a query to ensure that the values for the live table are the same as the most recent entries in the archive table?

PS  I'd prefer to handle this in SQL, but PL/SQL is also an option if it's faster.

Comment: What is the primary key?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT term, crn, fee, level_code
FROM live_data
MINUS
SELECT term, crn, fee, level_code
FROM historical_data
```

Whats on live but not in historical. Can then union to a reverse of this to get whats in historical but not live.

Comment: I'm not sure is the fastest but it's the only answer that actually works.

Answer (score 3):

Simply:

```
SELECT collist
  FROM TABLE A
minus 
SELECT collist
  FROM TABLE B
UNION ALL
SELECT collist
  FROM TABLE B
minus 
SELECT collist
  FROM TABLE A;
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention how rows are uniquely identified, so I've assumed you also have an "id" column:

```
SELECT *
FROM livetable
WHERE (term, crn, fee, levelcode) NOT IN (
   SELECT FIRST_VALUE(term) OVER (ORDER BY archivedate DESC)
         ,FIRST_VALUE(crn) OVER (ORDER BY archivedate DESC)
         ,FIRST_VALUE(fee) OVER (ORDER BY archivedate DESC)
         ,FIRST_VALUE(levelcode) OVER (ORDER BY archivedate DESC)
   FROM   archivetable
   WHERE  livetable.id = archivetable.id
);
```

Note: This query doesn't take NULLS into account - if any of the columns are nullable you can add suitable logic (e.g. NVL each column to some "impossible" value).

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no ID.  I'm just comparing the values listed.  Also, will this query help to identify records that are in archive but not live?  I need this to work both ways...

Comment: If you don't have a unique key, how would you know which set of "history records" in the archive table relate to each row in the live table?

Answer (score 0):

unload to table.unl
select * from table1 
order by 1,2,3,4

unload to table2.unl
select * from table2
order by 1,2,3,4

diff table1.unl table2.unl > diff.unl

Comment: Thanks for the try, but I can see this is wrong already.  My archive table will have multiple entries for multiple dates and this is going to return all of them, not the just the most recent.

On a side note, if you can help selecting * and referencing columns by number instead of name you'll be much better off.

Comment: Sorry Sonny.  I didn't understand the pk in the archive table.  I just caught the piece about the archive_date.  :)  As for * and 1,2,3,4 ... it is meant to give you the idea without me having to type out the columns.   My point was to unload the data and do a diff, but make sure that you use an order by clause.  Laziness is my superpower.  Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a query of the form:

```
SELECT your columns FROM your live table
EXCEPT
SELECT your columns FROM your archive table WHERE archive date is most recent;
```

Any results will be rows in your live table that are not in your most recent archive.

If you also need rows in your most recent archive that are not in your live table, simply reverse the order of the selects, and repeat, or get them all in the same query by performing a `(live UNION archive) EXCEPT (live INTERSECTION archive)`