# oracle find difference between 2 tables

Tags: oracle

I have 2 tables that are the same structure. One is a temp one and the other is a prod one. The entire data set gets loaded each time and sometimes this dataset will have deleted records from the prior datasets. I load the dataset into temp table first and if any records were deleted I want to deleted them from the prod table also.

So how can I find the records that exist in prod but not in temp? I tried outer join but it doesn't seem to be working. It's returning all the records from the table in the left or right depending on doing left or right outer join.

I then also want to delete those records in the prod table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to identify differences between two tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293092/fastest-way-to-identify-differences-between-two-tables)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One way would be to use the `MINUS` operator

```
SELECT * FROM table1
MINUS
SELECT * FROM table2
```

will show all the rows in `table1` that do not have an exact match in `table2` (you can obviously specify a smaller column list if you are only interested in determining whether a particular key exists in both tables).

Another would be to use a `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                     FROM table2 t2
                    WHERE t1.some_key = t2.some_key )
```

Comment: Hey that's pretty cool, I never knew of the `MINUS` command.  I always learn new things when you chime in.

Comment: Can you delete with the minus command? Not sure how that syntax would look like.

Comment: @user441521 - Sure.  You'd need to put the `MINUS` query in a subquery, e.g. `DELETE FROM table1 WHERE some_key IN (<<MINUS query>>)`.

Comment: @user441521 - You'd have to wrap it in a nested select.  `delete from foo where id in (select id from table1 minus select id from table2);`

Answer (score 3):

How about something like:

```
SELECT * FROM ProdTable WHERE ID NOT IN
   (select ID from TempTable);
```

It'd work the same as a `DELETE` statement as well:

```
DELETE FROM ProdTable WHERE ID NOT IN
   (select ID from TempTable);
```

Comment: bah, just remembered I can do outer join and then check for the other table column is null. totally forgot about that. But this works too. Thanks!

Comment: my join would be on about 6 columns. would the not in still work for that?

Comment: @user441521 - Yea, `NOT IN` will work just like any other operator would.

Answer (score 3):

MINUS can work here
The following statement combines results with the MINUS operator, which returns only rows returned by the first query but not by the second:

```
SELECT * FROM prod
MINUS
SELECT * FROM temp;
```

Minus will only work if the table structure is same