# How to find the different values between 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables and I want to find only the different values in 2 columns on one of the tables
(only the unique combination of 2 strings that is not in the first table  )

for example :
TABEL 1

| ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- |
| X1 | X2 |
| X3 | X4 |
| X5 | X6 |
| X3 | X4 |
| X6 | X7 |

TABEL 2 (the table I want to take the values from that are not in table1 )

| ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- |
| X1 | X2 |
| X3 | X4 |
| X5 | X6 |
| X4 | X3 |
| X1 | X9 |
| X3 | X12 |

the output will be :

| ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- |
| X1 | X9 |
| X3 | X12 |

Comment: Hints: `MINUS`. Or `NOT EXISTS`, or LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [oracle find difference between 2 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631224/oracle-find-difference-between-2-tables)

Comment: Why isn't the row (x4, x3) in the output? Is there a mistake in the first table (you have x3, x4 twice, perhaps one of them was meant to be x4, x3)?

Comment: Then: can ID1 or ID2 be null in either table, and if so, how to handle? If (x1, NULL) appears in both tables, does it need to appear in the result? In any case, unless the columns can't be NULL, make sure to test all proposed solutions for how they handle NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM Table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM Table1 t1
            WHERE (t1.ID1 = t2.ID1 AND t1.ID2 = t2.ID2)
               OR (t1.ID1 = t2.ID2 AND t1.ID2 = t2.ID1)
          );
```

or:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM Table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM Table1 t1
            WHERE LEAST(t1.ID1, t1.ID2) = LEAST(t2.ID1, t2.ID2)
              AND GREATEST(t1.ID1, t1.ID2) = GREATEST(t2.ID1, t2.ID2)
          );
```

or:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM Table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM Table1 t1
            WHERE (t1.ID1, t1.ID2) IN ((t2.ID1, t2.ID2), (t2.ID2, t2.ID1))
          );
```

or, with `MINUS`:

```
SELECT ID1, ID2 FROM Table2
MINUS
SELECT ID1, ID2 FROM Table1
MINUS 
SELECT ID2, ID1 FROM Table1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4752c635fec4598fb3fa531dea780528).

Answer (score 0):

One option uses exists logic:

```sql
SELECT t2.ID1, t2.ID2
FROM Table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table1 t1
    WHERE t1.ID1 = t2.ID1 AND
          t1.ID2 = t2.ID2
);
```

We can also use a left anti-join:

```sql
SELECT t2.ID1, t2.ID2
FROM Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
    ON t1.ID1 = t2.ID1 AND
       t1.ID2 = t2.ID2
WHERE t1.ID1 IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T2.ID1,T2.ID2
FROM TABLE2 T2
MINUS
SELECT T1.ID1,T1.ID2
FROM TABLE1 T1
```

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of
code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.